# varnish error sess_workspace

Tags: configuration, debian, varnish

**Metadata:** My system is debian 7 64bit

Hi, I am new to varnish and I have encountered an error that i cant seem to solve.
I have the following in my /etc/default/varnish configuration file:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
-T localhost:6082 \
-f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
-u www-data -g www-data \
-S /etc/varnish/secret \
-p thread_pools=2 \
-p thread_pool_min=25 \
-p thread_pool_max=250 \
-p thread_pool_add_delay=2 \
-p timeout_linger=50 \
-p sess_workspace=262144 \
-p cli_timeout=40 \
-s malloc,512m"
```

When I restarted he varnish service it failed with the error `Unknown parameter "sess_workspace".`
I checked the /var/log/varnish/ and no logs where generated.
I also checked `syslog` and the only logs that varnish wrote were logs that had to do with the startup and shutdown of varnish after he install and when I ran `service varnish restart`. Here ara all the relevant syslog entries (`cat syslog | grep varnish`):

```
Nov  6 00:56:27 HOSTNAME varnishd[7557]: Platform: Linux,3.2.0-4-amd64,x86_64,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit
Nov  6 00:56:27 HOSTNAME varnishd[7557]: child (7618) Started
Nov  6 00:56:27 HOSTNAME varnishd[7557]: Child (7618) said Child starts
Nov  6 01:04:58 HOSTNAME varnishd[7557]: Manager got SIGINT
Nov  6 01:04:58 HOSTNAME varnishd[7557]: Stopping Child
Nov  6 01:04:59 HOSTNAME varnishd[7557]: Child (7618) ended
Nov  6 01:04:59 HOSTNAME varnishd[7557]: Child (7618) said Child dies
Nov  6 01:04:59 HOSTNAME varnishd[7557]: Child cleanup complete
```

I have searched the vast seas of google but with no luck (I have even compared with example code from varnish  site and still no luck).

Any ideas that may help me?

Answer (score 0):

Bit delayed but in case anyone else has this issue I will post what I found.

Found this here: http://www.0550go.com/proxy/varnish/varnish-v4-config.html

> sess_workspace
>   In 3.0 it was often necessary to increase
>   sess_workspace if a lot of VMODs, complex header operations or ESI
>   were in use.
>
> This is no longer necessary, because ESI scratch space
>   happens elsewhere in 4.0.
>
> If you are using a lot of VMODs, you may
>   need to increase either workspace_backend and workspace_client based
>   on where your VMOD is doing its work.